# Showing whole DIV in IE (jQuery slider)

Tags: jquery, html, slider

IE somehow shows the whole `DIV` when the page loads before it resizes to the right size. Is it possible to avoid this since it is really ugly?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/216925/luuk

In FF it works perfectly fine (not the layout fully, but the slider).

Comment: sorry i added the wrong link:
http://www.bbp.nl/luuk-test/wac/

Answer (score 0):

IE's javaScript rendering engine (excluding IE9) is horribly slow, and in IE your DOM/HTML will always be displayed with a slight delay prior to any JS being executed. You need to either set styles via CSS manually or make your div hidden and run it through the process of resize->delay->fadeIn.

**CSS:**

```
<style> #yourDiv { visibility:hidden; } </style>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#yourDiv').width(...).height(...).delay(100).fadeIn(500);
```